# Timestamp to indicate the latest event writing in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to know if there is any way to find out when the latest event was writing to a table in SQL Server.

Assuming the table does not have a `created_at`/`updated_at` columns and CDC and Change Capture are NOT enabled on the table.

I don't want to stream data out of this approach; I know I can use CDC or CT to do so, but I'm trying to find a way to check if table X is active and have inserts/updates for monitoring purposes only. I don't want the actual data that was writing I just want a timestamp indicating the table was affected with insert or update.

I've been checking `sys.tables` and I found columns such as `create_date` and `modify_date` but its related to table existence and schema changes and not the underlying data but it gave me hope that it might be available in one of SQL Server undocumented system tables.

Thank you.